# How can I determine if my convolution is separable?

Tags: math, image-processing, signal-processing, convolution

What makes a convolution kernel separable? How would I be able to tell what those separable parts were in order to do two 1D convolutions instead of a 2D convolution>

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the 2D filter kernel has a `rank` of 1 then it is separable. You can test this in e.g. Matlab or Octave:

```
octave-3.2.3:1>     sobel = [-1 0 1 ; -2 0 2 ; -1 0 1];
octave-3.2.3:2>     rank(sobel)
ans =  1
octave-3.2.3:3>
```

See also: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/11/28/separable-convolution-part-2/ - this covers using `SVD` (Singular Value Decomposition) to extract the two 1D kernels from a separable 2D kernel.

See also this question on [DSP.stackexchange.com](http://DSP.stackexchange.com): [Fast/efficient way to decompose separable integer 2D filter coefficients](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/fast-efficient-way-to-decompose-separable-integer-2d-filter-coefficients)

Comment: SVD is the way to go here. Separable (ie. rank 1) kernels are very specific, and SVD allows you to approximate your kernel by a (small) sum of separable ones.

Answer (score 4):

you can also split the matrix into symmetric and skew parts and separate each part, which can be effective for larger 2d convolutions.

Comment: can you give example to clarify?

Comment: If you can arrange your 2d matrix as the vector product `x.y' +u.v'` etc you can do a set of 1d convolutions of the rows and columns in stead of the 2d convolution, needing only 4N multiply/adds rather than N^2. If the `u.v'` has a smaller size then the reduction is greater. This usually assumes you have prior knowledge of the matrix's structure to ease the separation. It will also depend on your compute engine - a GPU may favour another structure.